# Formatted Date in Attribute using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I'm looking at adding a title tag to a element with a formated date from an attribute.  The input value is DateTime UTC format and i needes to be output in "pretty format".

I have a template that transforms the value.  However I can't figure out how to call this template when puting the value into an attribute.

```
  <xsl:template name="formatDate">
    <xsl:param name="dateTime" />
    <xsl:variable name="date" select="substring-before($dateTime, 'T')" />
    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring-before($date, '-')" />
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring-before(substring-after($date, '-'), '-')" />
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring-after(substring-after($date, '-'), '-')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($month, '-', $day, '-', $year)" />
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: US date format pretty? Well, I guess beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: The term is quite relative.  I would imagine that to Local Users (AKA Lusers) US date format is prettier than UTC

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:attribute name="title">
  <xsl:call-template name="formatDate">
    <xsl:with-param name="dateTime" select="@lastReported" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:attribute>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to re-use the same value, you could also do:

```
<xsl:variable name="title">
  <xsl:call-template name="formatDate">
    <xsl:with-param name="dateTime" select="@lastReported" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>

<dummy titile="{$title}"/>
```

Comment: +1 I prefer to call templates from within a variable, even if I don't need to reuse the same value, just because I think it makes the code cleaner. It is much easier, in my opinion, to read the element/attributes when using variables/AVTs than using xsl:variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XSLT 2.0, you can skip calling a template all together and use `format-dateTime()`:

```
<foo title="{format-dateTime(@lastReported,'[M]-[D]-[Y]')}"/>
```

Comment: +1 it looks very clean. This function is proper of XSLT 2.0 spec. and I've missed it looking at the XPath 2.0.